# How to calibrate the laptop battery on 12.04

Tags: power-management, shutdown, battery

Since a couple of days or so my laptop (asus n76vm) does a hard shut-down when the battery indicates 20% life left. It just cuts off the power, no shut-down screen or anything, making the hard drive do that nasty 'scratchy' sound.

What should I do now? It seems the battery is less powerfull than it was before (which makes sense) but the OS didn't keep track. How should I go about re-calibrating the battery?

Answer (score 9):

Have you tried power-calibrate ?

```
sudo apt install power-calibrate
```

then run

```
power-calibrate -r
```

You can read [the manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/power-calibrate.8.html) or run `man power-calibrate` for more information.

Comment: I had to run the command with sudo, like `sudo power-calibrate -p`. "-r" argument needs seconds value as well. Maybe the command has changed. I'm on Debian Buster.

Comment: power-calibrate seems to *display* information only, not to configure the OS with it. Am I wrong on my reading of the man ?

Answer (score 8):

**Update**
As per the latest version of **power-calibrate**, use this command

```
power-calibrate  -R -r 20 -d 5 -s 21 -n 0 -p
```

Where

```
-d secs  specify a delay before starting
-h show  help
-n CPUs  specify the number of CPUs to exercise
-o file  output results into YAML formatted file
-p       show progress
-r secs  specify run duration in seconds of each test cycle
-R       use Intel RAPL per CPU package data to measure Watts
-s num   number of samples (tests) per CPU for CPU calibration
```

Comment: Should I run the command while charging or with the battery only?

Comment: Not sure but I think  it won't be a deal, you can run that either in charging or unplugged in my case I was plugged

Comment: does this command only display information or does it actually calibrate?

Comment: My System76 Galago Pro has no RAPL domains, so it had to discharge so that the power usage could be measured.