# battery caliberation

Tags: laptop, battery

I am using HP 15 R 074TU laptop.

Laptop is not getting charged continuously, charging is getting disconnected for every 1 minute and getting connected again for another minute.

If I remove the battery I am able to use it with out any trouble.

Is this a problem with battery? Should I change the battery?

I need to check battery and [How to calibrate the laptop battery on 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/446084/how-to-calibrate-the-laptop-battery-on-12-04) says how to  check.

I did

```
sudo apt install power-calibrate
```

and then

```
power-calibrate -r
```

I do not understand what to judge from here.

Are there any other ways to calibrate battery?

Running

```
    power-calibrate -r
```

says the following

```
praphulla@praphulla:~$ power-calibrate -r
power-calibrate: option requires an argument -- 'r'
power-calibrate, version 0.01.21

usage: power-calibrate [options]
 -d secs  specify delay before starting
 -h show  help
 -n cpus  specify number of CPUs to exercise
 -o file  output results into YAML formatted file
 -p       show progress
 -r secs  specify run duration in seconds of each test cycle
 -R       use Intel RAPL per CPU package data to measure Watts
 -s num   number of samples (tests) per CPU for CPU calibration

Example: power-calibrate  -R -r 20 -d 5 -s 21 -n 0 -p
praphulla@praphulla:~$ sudo apt install power-calibrate
[sudo] password for praphulla: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
power-calibrate is already the newest version (0.01.21-1).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.4.0-124 linux-headers-4.4.0-124-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-124-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-124-generic
  linux-signed-image-4.4.0-124-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 32 not upgraded.
praphulla@praphulla:~$ power-calibrate -r
power-calibrate: option requires an argument -- 'r'
power-calibrate, version 0.01.21

usage: power-calibrate [options]
 -d secs  specify delay before starting
 -h show  help
 -n cpus  specify number of CPUs to exercise
 -o file  output results into YAML formatted file
 -p       show progress
 -r secs  specify run duration in seconds of each test cycle
 -R       use Intel RAPL per CPU package data to measure Watts
 -s num   number of samples (tests) per CPU for CPU calibration

Example: power-calibrate  -R -r 20 -d 5 -s 21 -n 0 -p
```

Running power-calibrate -R -r 20 -d 5 -s 21 -n 0 -p says the following :

```
praphulla@praphulla:~$ power-calibrate -R -r 20 -d 5 -s 21 -n 0 -p
  CPU load  User   Sys  Idle  Run  Ctxt/s  IRQ/s  Ops/s Cycl/s Inst/s  Watts
    0% x 1   5.8   1.4  92.3  1.9  4405.9  678.4   0.0    1.4K 221.2   4.549
    5% x 1  29.8   5.2  63.4  1.9  9800.8 2426.1  14.9M  84.2M 209.4M  7.037
   10% x 1  13.9   2.3  82.6  2.5  4845.2  984.6  27.6M 151.5M 387.1M  5.116
   15% x 1   8.6   1.3  89.7  1.4  2695.8  594.5  42.6M 231.5M   0.6B  4.286
   20% x 1   8.6   0.9  90.2  2.0  3048.1  651.6  60.8M 328.8M   0.9B  4.532
   25% x 1   7.4   0.3  92.3  1.4   731.7  370.0  76.0M 410.0M   1.1B  3.846
   30% x 1  12.5   1.0  85.9  1.6  2985.2  784.5  92.2M   0.5B   1.3B  4.892
   35% x 1  10.3   0.4  89.2  1.6  1118.5  539.8 108.6M   0.6B   1.5B  4.440
   40% x 1   9.5   0.5  89.8  1.9  1294.6  522.1 121.7M   0.7B   1.7B  4.559
   45% x 1  12.5   0.4  87.1  1.6  1071.9  539.3 139.3M   0.8B   2.0B  4.586
   50% x 1  14.0   0.4  85.6  1.6  1072.3  619.0 154.3M   0.8B   2.2B  4.663
   55% x 1  15.1   0.4  84.4  2.1  1160.5  641.5 169.3M   0.9B   2.4B  4.803
   60% x 1  16.3   0.5  83.1  1.9  1090.9  682.5 184.3M   1.0B   2.6B  4.990
   65% x 1  17.3   0.4  81.7  1.5  1199.6  724.9 199.5M   1.1B   2.8B  5.130
   70% x 1  18.5   0.4  81.0  1.8  1204.7  672.6 214.7M   1.2B   3.0B  5.341
   75% x 1  19.7   0.4  79.8  2.4  1149.2  671.0 228.8M   1.2B   3.2B  5.497
   80% x 1  19.9   0.3  79.8  1.9  1179.4  659.8 227.2M   1.2B   3.2B  5.550
   85% x 1  25.0   1.3  73.5  2.4  2415.1  963.8 258.9M   1.4B   3.6B  6.071
   90% x 1  25.4   0.7  73.4  2.3  3333.7  958.3 276.4M   1.5B   3.9B  6.201
   95% x 1  43.7   3.9  51.8  2.6  7346.6 2480.7 283.9M   1.6B   4.0B  7.347
  100% x 1  41.4   2.9  55.0  3.6  5460.9 1474.6 309.9M   1.7B   4.3B  7.176

For 1 CPU (of a 4 CPU system):
  Power (Watts) = (% CPU load * 8.379343e-02) + 3.637306
  1% CPU load is about 83.79 mW
  Coefficient of determination R^2 = 0.951575 (very strong)

  Energy (Watt-seconds) = (bogo op * 5.905279e-09) + 4.369853
  1 bogo op is about 5.91 nWs
  Coefficient of determination R^2 = 0.322311 (very weak)

  Energy (Watt-seconds) = (CPU cycle * 1.100644e-09) + 4.360759
  1 CPU cycle is about 1.10 nWs
  Coefficient of determination R^2 = 0.331482 (very weak)

  Energy (Watt-seconds) = (CPU instruction * 4.217149e-10) + 4.369790
  1 CPU instruction is about 421.71 pWs
  Coefficient of determination R^2 = 0.322276 (very weak)
```

I checked again now (29/June/2018, 5:40 PM) with same command and it says

```
praphulla@praphulla:~$ power-calibrate -R -r 20 -d 5 -s 21 -n 0 -p
  CPU load  User   Sys  Idle  Run  Ctxt/s  IRQ/s  Ops/s Cycl/s Inst/s  Watts
    0% x 1   0.2   0.1  99.5  1.1   133.2   53.0   0.0    1.2K 223.9   2.836
    5% x 1   1.5   0.1  98.3  1.1   138.0   75.8  11.9M  64.4M 167.4M  2.967
   10% x 1   2.7   0.1  97.2  1.4   163.3   98.3  21.6M 116.7M 303.3M  3.149
   15% x 1   3.9   0.1  96.0  1.2   203.1  128.2  38.2M 205.7M   0.5B  3.350
   20% x 1   5.7   0.0  94.2  1.1   251.8  174.2  61.0M 328.4M   0.9B  3.580
   25% x 1   6.3   0.1  93.6  1.7   288.8  200.4  78.2M 420.7M   1.1B  3.685
   30% x 1   7.3   0.1  92.6  1.3   310.9  218.7  93.5M   0.5B   1.3B  3.806
   35% x 1   8.7   0.1  91.1  1.3   361.0  254.8 108.9M   0.6B   1.5B  3.958
   40% x 1   8.2   0.1  91.7  1.6   370.1  257.4 122.0M   0.7B   1.7B  4.108
   45% x 1  11.2   0.1  88.7  1.9   397.8  301.8 139.4M   0.8B   2.0B  4.302
   50% x 1  12.4   0.1  87.4  1.4   439.2  337.4 154.7M   0.8B   2.2B  4.519
   55% x 1  13.7   0.2  86.0  1.6   486.3  366.2 169.7M   0.9B   2.4B  4.755
   60% x 1  14.8   0.1  85.0  1.7   489.4  386.7 184.8M   1.0B   2.6B  4.849
   65% x 1  15.7   0.1  83.8  2.2   518.9  409.4 199.8M   1.1B   2.8B  4.963
   70% x 1  17.2   0.2  82.5  1.7   592.4  462.4 214.7M   1.2B   3.0B  5.031
   75% x 1  18.2   0.2  81.5  1.8   599.2  472.9 229.5M   1.2B   3.2B  5.201
   80% x 1  18.6   0.2  81.1  1.9   612.8  484.6 238.7M   1.3B   3.3B  5.312
   85% x 1  21.0   0.1  78.9  2.3   655.1  535.1 261.8M   1.4B   3.7B  5.571
   90% x 1  22.1   0.2  77.6  1.9   695.0  567.2 278.1M   1.5B   3.9B  5.870
   95% x 1  23.3   0.2  76.4  1.9   730.4  593.0 293.1M   1.6B   4.1B  6.043
  100% x 1  25.1   0.0  74.8  2.5   130.9  317.3 316.7M   1.7B   4.4B  6.155

For 1 CPU (of a 4 CPU system):
  Power (Watts) = (% CPU load * 1.341409e-01) + 2.802643
  1% CPU load is about 134.14 mW
  Coefficient of determination R^2 = 0.995768 (very strong)

  Energy (Watt-seconds) = (bogo op * 1.045605e-08) + 2.875304
  1 bogo op is about 10.46 nWs
  Coefficient of determination R^2 = 0.996404 (very strong)

  Energy (Watt-seconds) = (CPU cycle * 1.948906e-09) + 2.872032
  1 CPU cycle is about 1.95 nWs
  Coefficient of determination R^2 = 0.996239 (very strong)

  Energy (Watt-seconds) = (CPU instruction * 7.466622e-10) + 2.875320
  1 CPU instruction is about 0.75 nWs
  Coefficient of determination R^2 = 0.996405 (very strong)
```

Comment: You didn't specify how many seconds as to what the `-r` is looking for.  Try running the example shown there of `power-calibrate  -R -r 20 -d 5 -s 21 -n 0 -p`

Comment: @Terrance I have added the output.. please see

Comment: Chances are you might have a bad battery.  You can try a power reset procedure of pulling all power from your computer after you power it off, including the battery and the power supply.  Then press the power button a few times or hold it down for about 15 seconds with no power.  Then connect the battery and the power supply back up and try again.  If it is still failing or charging and stopping, look into possibly a new battery.

Comment: @Terrance I run the command again and I have edited the post to show the output. please see that