# Battery recalibration - 18.04

Tags: 18.04, battery

Ok, so I'm not fully understanding how to recalibrate my batter. I followed [How to calibrate the laptop battery on 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/446084/how-to-calibrate-the-laptop-battery-on-12-04) and so I ran the following:

```
xxx:~ $ power-calibrate -R -r 120 -d 5 -s 21 -n 0 -p
  CPU load  User   Sys  Idle  Run  Ctxt/s  IRQ/s  Ops/s  Watts
    0% x 1   2.3   0.7  97.0  1.2   691.0  255.0   0.0   0.709
    5% x 1   3.6   0.7  95.7  1.2  1163.8  291.9  10.6M  0.791
   10% x 1   4.7   0.6  94.7  1.3   757.2  302.5  22.6M  0.831
   15% x 1   5.8   0.6  93.6  1.3   778.3  331.8  35.8M  0.904
   20% x 1   7.1   0.6  92.2  1.3   829.2  373.1  47.9M  0.983
   25% x 1   8.5   0.7  90.8  1.5   952.4  442.7  59.1M  1.064
   30% x 1   9.4   0.6  90.0  1.4   875.7  419.9  74.3M  1.122
   35% x 1  10.5   0.6  88.9  1.4   889.1  438.4  88.2M  1.195
   40% x 1  11.6   0.6  87.8  1.6   928.1  473.3 100.5M  1.266
   45% x 1  12.8   0.6  86.6  1.5   957.0  505.3 114.0M  1.336
   50% x 1  14.0   0.7  85.3  1.8   987.8  541.1 126.7M  1.412
   55% x 1  15.0   0.6  84.4  1.7  1010.8  557.0 139.1M  1.473
   60% x 1  15.1   0.5  84.4  1.8  1064.2  574.6 162.2M  1.615
   65% x 1  16.7   0.5  82.8  1.8  1074.8  592.1 172.8M  1.671
   70% x 1  18.0   0.6  81.4  1.9  1098.0  618.4 184.0M  1.725
   75% x 1  19.0   0.6  80.4  1.8  1184.8  674.5 214.7M  2.006
   80% x 1  20.5   0.6  78.9  2.0  1153.5  677.8 211.9M  1.862
   85% x 1  19.5   0.5  80.0  1.9  1195.0  677.4 242.5M  1.974
   90% x 1  22.0   0.3  77.7  1.9  1633.7  915.2 442.2M  4.304
   95% x 1  24.4   0.3  75.3  2.0  1721.2  983.8   0.5B  5.057
  100% x 1  26.2   0.3  73.6  2.2   694.1  491.0   0.6B  6.595

For 1 CPU (of a 4 CPU system):
  Power (Watts) = (% CPU load * 1.796812e-01) + -0.654258
  1% CPU load is about 179.68 mW
  Coefficient of determination R^2 = 0.644934 (weak)

  Energy (Watt-seconds) = (bogo op * 9.092169e-09) + 0.353925
  1 bogo op is about 9.09 nWs
  Coefficient of determination R^2 = 0.962223 (very strong)
```

But now nothing has happened. My battery estimates are still completely wrong. What do I do with the `power-calibrate` information once I have it? or is it supposed to do everything on its own?

Note that I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Would really like to know wtf that one answer was thinking, I found it and then your question. It seems nobody has an answer to how to recalibrate a battery in Ubuntu.

Comment: I have the same question. What do you do with the results of the test other than looking at them and thinking now what?