# Calibrate Ubuntu 20.04 battery

Tags: 20.04, battery

How to calibrate ubuntu battery. I tried charging it to 100% & then tried to discharge it completely. But when the battery % was less than 3%, it automatically hibernated. I was not able to discharge it completely.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calibrate the laptop battery on 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/446084/how-to-calibrate-the-laptop-battery-on-12-04).  Completely discharging your battery doesn't calibrate anything.  But a power interruption in the middle of a session can definitely destroy your system; that's why it hibernates before it gets to that point.

Comment: I hope so. But I can't confirm. I need more time. I did run `power-calibrate  -R -r 20 -d 5 -s 21 -n 0 -p`