# Ubuntu 20.04 battery reading error and instant shutdown

Tags: 20.04, power-management, shutdown, laptop, battery

I shifted from Windows 8.1 to ubuntu 20.04 like a week or two before. My laptop name is **Lenovo Notebook 15-ay542tu.** It shows when the battery is full by glowing white.
Today i noticed that when battery percentage shown on the screen is around 80% the white light starts glowing. Also it takes around 40 minutes to reach 80% but then 1 hour to from 80% to 100%.

I also noticed that when the battery percentage goes down to 20% then I see a battery low notification and then it instantly drops to 5-6% or sometimes shutdown.

Is this my battery problem or I have done somethhing wrong to my OS ?

Comment: from what you said, there could be 2 possible conclusion. Either you need to calibrate your battery or your battery is damaged. You can read how to calibrate battery from here :https://www.gearbest.com/blog/how-to/how-to-calibrate-your-laptop-battery-correctly-and-safely-415. If you wish to do so in Ubuntu you can read this post : https://askubuntu.com/questions/446084/how-to-calibrate-the-laptop-battery-on-12-04. if you face same problem even after battery calibration then your battery is damaged. If it's an OS issue then you should not face this in Windows

Comment: it was perfectly alright in windows.

Comment: I don't think so. Adding RAM does not affect you battery that much to the point where you could notice it. If you are observing this only in Ubuntu and your windows is running fine, then I recommend checking `/etc/UPower/UPower.conf` and if you haven't calibrated your battery try doing so.